# Camel ActiveMQ how to destroy/purge a virtual topic queue without consumers

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

My application consists of many OSGi bundles running inside JBoss Fuse 6.2.1. Each bundle has a Camel route consuming from an ActiveMQ endpoint. Data is exchanged using [VirtualTopics](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html).

**ProducerBundle** publishes to topic `VirtualTopic.MyTopic`

**ConsumerBundle A** consumes from queue `Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.MyTopic`
**ConsumerBundle B** consumes from queue `Consumer.B.VirtualTopic.MyTopic`
**ConsumerBundle C** consumes from queue `Consumer.C.VirtualTopic.MyTopic`

At a certain moment in time Consumer C is closed, its bundle uninstalled and will never come back. Howewer, messages are still enqueued into `Consumer.C.VirtualTopic.MyTopic` queue.
**How do I destroy such queue?**

ActiveMQ pauses the Producer when the queue fills up, and I cannot set a small time to live on the message as other consumers may take a while to process each message. I cannot modify the VirtualTopic structure. I have full access to 
ActiveMQ configuration and Camel routes.
**Are there any other options to handle the situation?**

```
<!-- producer route -->
<route id="ProducerRoute"/>
    <from uri="direct:trigger"/>
    <to uri="activemq:topic:VirtualTopic.MyTopic"/>
</route>

<!-- each consumer route -->
<route id="ConsumerARoute">
    <from uri="activemq:Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.MyTopic"/>
    <to uri="bean:myProcessor"/>
</route>
```

Comment: You can set a timeToLive on messages.

Comment: If the Consumer C bundle is uninstalled by hand, maybe you can also delete the queue by hand (through the web console or via jmx).

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis if I set a TTL too small, other consumers may lose messages; if it's big enough the producer is slowed down, thus slowing the whole process. I am hoping on some event/trigger/interceptor offered by ActiveMQ or Camel instead of writing my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for the aggressive solution: I hook into OSGi bundle lifecycle, when it is stopped I use JMX MBeanServer to destroy the now unneeded queues.

Since my bundle is managed using blueprint, I opted for a bean with a destroy method.
Here's an example implementation:

My bean

```
package org.darugna.osgi;

import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

public class QueueDestroyer {

    private static final String[] QUEUES_TO_DESTROY = {
        "Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.MyTopic"
    };

    private MBeanServer mBeanServer;

    public void setMbeanServer(MBeanServer mBeanServer) {
        this.mBeanServer = mBeanServer;
    }

    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        ObjectName brokerName = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=amq");
        for (String queueName : QUEUES_TO_DESTROY) {
            Object returnValue = mBeanServer.invoke(brokerName,
                    "removeQueue",
                    new Object[]{queueName},
                    new String[]{String.class.getName()});
        }
    }

}
```

Blueprint.xml

```
<blueprint>

    <reference id="mbeanServer" interface="javax.management.MBeanServer" 
               availability="mandatory"/>

    <bean id="queueDestroyer" class="org.darugna.osgi.QueueDestroyer" 
          destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="mbeanServer" ref="mbeanServer"/>
    </bean>

    <camelContext>
        <route>
            <from uri="activemq:Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.MyTopic"/>
            <to uri="bean:myProcessor"/>
        </route>
    <camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Apache ActiveMQ documentation how you can delete inactive queues/topics such as: http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html

Comment: Thanks @Claus I was thinking about that solution, but the link says: " **if** they are **empty** for 30 seconds". If the queue receives a message after the consumer is closed, the problem remains. I see that I can configure such timeouts, I'll give it another try.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar situation, but I couldn't use the Claus's suggestion because in my broker there are other queues that have no consumer and I doesn't want to delete them. 
In my case I'm running a JBoss Fuse 6.1.0 with fabric (I think that is the same with newer version of Fuse): I just removed the consumer (in my case I just removed the profile with the consumer) and after that I deleted the queue with the delete button in the hawtio console.

Comment: You're right, my mistake :) 
Now I'm adding a more significant answer.